# Can every commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra be interpreted by an algebra of functions on some space?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given any commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$, does there exist a topological space $X$ such that $C(X)=A$, where $C(X)$ is the commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Furthermore, for any commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$, can we construct a smooth manifold $M$ so that $C^∞(M)=A$, where $C^∞(M)$ is the commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of smooth functions on $M$?

Comment: I once saw a talk by Kirillov in which he said, "Let $C^\infty(X)$ be an algebra..." So I think the answer is yes, perhaps with certain additional assumptions on $A$.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know more detial about that. Could you tell me some references?

Comment: No subalgebra of any $C(X)$ can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How is your advice relevant to my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! Commutative $\mathbb{R}$ algebras may have nilpotent elements. For instance, in the algebra $A=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$, $x^2=0$ but $x\ne 0$. On the other hand, if a real valued function is nilpotent, then it is zero.

This encourages a restricted question: if a commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$ has no non-zero nilpotents ($\operatorname{rad}(A)=0$), must it be isomorphic to $C(X)$ for a space $X$? In this case, one finds that $A$ can be embedded into $C(X)$ where $X=\operatorname{spec}(A)$ is the spectrum (with the Zariski topology). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring

*The above is not quite right actually. Because $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed, there are counterexamples. For instance $A=\mathbb{C}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra which cannot be embedded into $C(X)$ for any space $X$, as freakish has said in a comment. Indeed, there is no function in $C(X)$ with $f^2=-1$.

The situation is closer to what you want when $A$ carries a compatible topology, such as if $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, then you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation
which allows you to realise $A$ as a subalgebra of $C(X)$ for a compact  Hausdorff $X$.

Comment: I agree, thank you. What is an assumption so that the embedding will be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

The complex algebras of the form $C(\text{compact space},\mathbb{C})$ are precisely the commutative $C^*$-algebras ([Gelfand duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation)). The real subalgebra of continuous functions to $\mathbb{R}$ is the subalgebra of self-adjoint elements.

The algebras of the form $C^{\infty}(\text{manifold})$ have been classified at [MO/21168](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21168/).

Comment: Thank you. I will learn operator theory.